# Javascript function returns NaN

Tags: javascript, nan

I really need some help with this one. The function is supposed to calculate the estimated closing costs. But for some reason the result is always "NaN" whatever I do with it. Can anyone help me out? I have no idea where it goes wrong.

```
function calc_closing_costs(form) {
    var purch_price = document.getElementById('purch_price');
    var ont_ltt = 0;
    if ((isNaN(parseInt(purch_price.value, 10))) || purch_price === "") {
        alert("You must enter a number!");
    } else if (parseInt(purch_price.value, 10) < 0) {
        alert("You must enter a positive number!");
    }
    if (400000 < parseInt(purch_price.value, 10)) {
        ont_ltt = (parseInt(purch_price.value, 10) - 400000) * 0.02 + 4475;
    } else {
        if (250000 < parseInt(purch_price.value, 10)) {
            ont_ltt = (parseInt(purch_price.value, 10) - 250000) * 0.015 + 2225;
        } else {
            if (55000 < parseInt(purch_price.value, 10)) {
                ont_ltt = (parseInt(purch_price.value, 10) - 55000) * 0.01 + 275;
            } else {
                ont_ltt = parseInt(purch_price.value, 10) * 0.005;
            }
        }
    }
    var legal_fees = document.getElementById('legal_fees');
    var closing_adj = document.getElementById('closing_adj');
    var result = document.getElementById('result');

    if (purch_price.value === "" || purch_price.value != parseFloat(purch_price.value)) {
        purch_price.value = 0;
    }
    if (legal_fees.value === "" || legal_fees.value != parseFloat(legal_fees.value)) {
        legal_fees.value = 0;
    }
    if (closing_adj.value === "" || closing_adj.value != parseFloat(closing_adj.value)) {
        closing_adj.value = 0;
    }
    result.value = 0;
    result.value = parseInt(result.value, 10);
    result.value = parseInt(ont_ltt.value, 10) + parseInt(legal_fees.value, 10) + parseInt(closing_adj.value, 10);
    document.getElementById("tecc").innerHTML = result.value;
}
```

Comment: Your code shouldn't keep calling `parseInt()` on the same thing over and over and over again. Call it once and save the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
    result.value = parseInt(ont_ltt.value, 10) + parseInt(legal_fees.value, 10) + parseInt(closing_adj.value, 10);
```

doesn't make sense — "ont_ltt" is a JavaScript variable, not a page element.

It should just be:

```
     result.value = ont_ltt + parseInt(legal_fees.value, 10) + parseInt(closing_adj.value, 10);
```

Well, *maybe* it should; you didn't post the page or the overall plan for what you're trying to do.  Using `parseInt()` in particular seems questionable. It will always give you an integer and truncate any fractional part of the value (anything after a decimal point).

Comment: Hey, Pointy! Thanks for your response. I removed the unnecessary parseInt from the code (and by unnecessary I mean I removed them one by one and checked if the script was still working, I'm a newbie as you can see) and putting ont_ltt instead of parseInt(ont_ltt.value,10) helped. It finally gives me a number! Thanks a lot! I really appreciate your help.